# When I open a folder in Nautilus all of the files rearrange themselves

Tags: nautilus

When I open a folder on my HDD in Nautilus, the files rearrange themselves. If the folder contains a lot of files, this process can take a good few seconds. This is inconvenient, as I have to wait for everything to settle before I can find a file that I am looking for. 
The files in the HDD are on an NTFS partition.

Is it possible for me to make the rearranging not happen? If so, how?

Comment: Do you have an ageing and/or slow HDD?

Comment: @pomsky My computer has an HDD and an SSD. They are less than a year old. I did some testing, and the rearranging only happens to files on the HDD. I will add this info to the question.

Comment: It's dumb, but worth asking - Did you install the ntfs-3g package? Dont think it would work otherwise, but who knows. Also, what kind of machine is this? CPU? RAM? How is the HDD connected? Internally or through a usb cable?

Comment: @jwcooper I did install ntfs-3g. It is an HP Pavilion laptop, i7-8550U CPU, 8 gigs RAM. The HDD is internal; it is 2 terabytes.

Comment: Try to open it from a terminal and see if any errors or posted. So, open terminal and type `nautilus` and then post back any messages you get. Also, how much space is taken up on that 2TB drive?

Comment: @jwcooper When I open nautilus from the terminal, no messages appear. The drive is 32.9% full.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to post this as an answer because I don't see many other options here. So, there is already an open bug report for Nautilus being slow when opening with lots of files (never got a response as to how many files you had on the drive). It's been open for a really long time with no resolution [Nautilus Bug Report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nautilus/+bug/869793)

Assuming this is your problem, the only solution would be to install a different file manager that doesn't have that problem (Dolphin and Midnight Commander are specifically mentioned in the bug report as not having that issue).

Another possible solution would be to re-install Nautilus. This has worked for people who saw errors displayed when opening Nautilus through the terminal. To do that: `sudo apt-get install --reinstall nautilus`

Other than that, you could move your files over to your SSD (if you have space), open a new Nautilus browser and see if the problem persists (assumes the problem is in software and doesn't depend on disk read times which will obviously be faster with the SSD). I wish I could have provided a silver bullet to speed up Nautilus, but there doesn't appear to be one. Check the health of your disk also using the "Disks" application and see if that reports any problems with your spinning HDD. Please respond if any of these work for you.

Comment: Thank you. I went into this thinking that I might have to change my file manager to fix my problem. I will try out Dolphin and if it lacks the problem, I will mark yours as the answer.

Comment: I have tried Dolphin and the problem is not there. Thank you.

Comment: No problem. Glad it worked and thanks for following up.